# Stub methodcalls with delegate / lambda parameters

Tags: unit-testing, lambda, mocking, rhino-mocks, func

I have a interface and class that looks like this:

```
public interface IServiceFacade
{
     TResult Execute<TResult>(Func<IService, TResult> operation);
}

public class ServiceFacade : IServiceFacade
{
    private readonly string endpoint = "EndPoint";

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Func<IService, TResult> operation)
    {
         // Call to remote WCF service that results in a TResult

         return TResult;
    }
}
```

The `IService` interface represent a WCF service running remotely, thus no implementationinstance of this interface is available in the class.

And i call this method twice like this:

```
public class ServiceConsumer
{
     public ServiceConsumer(IServiceFacade serviceFacade)
     {
         var returnInteger1 = serviceFacade.Execute(service => service.Method1("StringArgument1"));
         var returnInteger2 = serviceFacade.Execute(service => service.Method1("StringArgument2"));
     }
}
```

In my unit test I want to stub the returnvalue of the first call to be 1 and the second call to be 2.

Example testmethod

```
[Test]
public void TestMethod()
{
    var serviceFacadeStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IServiceFacade>();
    serviceFacadeStub.Stub(call => call.Execute(Arg<Func<IService, int>.Matches(?))).Return(1);     
    serviceFacadeStub.Stub(call => call.Execute(Arg<Func<IService, int>.Matches(?))).Return(2);

    var sut = new ServiceConsumer(serviceFacadeStub);    

}
```

I can't figure out what to put in `Matches`, or maybe im better off using something other than matches.

Right now im using RhinoMocks and NUnit but if theres a better framework to do this im open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases mocking methods with `Func`/`Action` is a little bit tricky(In any mock framework I know...)

Usually you have to execute the given `Func`/`Action` and then the result should affect the rest of the unit under test.

The following snippet shows the easist way to solve your problem:

```
[Test]
public void TestMethod(
{

    var fakeService = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IService>();
    fakeService.Stub(x => x.Method1("StringArgument1")).Return(1);
    fakeService.Stub(x => x.Method1("StringArgument2")).Return(2);

    var serviceFacadeStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IServiceFacade>();
    serviceFacadeStub.Stub(call => call.Execute(Arg<Func<IService, int>>.Is.Anything))
            .WhenCalled(invocation =>
            {
                var func = (Func<IService, int>)invocation.Arguments[0];
                invocation.ReturnValue = func(fakeService);
            }).Return(0);

    var shouldBeOne = serviceFacadeStub.Execute(service => service.Method1("StringArgument1"));
    var shouldBeTwo = serviceFacadeStub.Execute(service => service.Method1("StringArgument2"));

    Assert.AreEqual(1, shouldBeOne);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, shouldBeTwo);

}
```

I execute the lambda with `fakeService` then return the result based on the given argument.
Another option is to use `Matches` as you did, but then you'll have to use reflection to analyze the lambda...(It is much more complicated....)

Answer (score 0):

Just incase someone else has the same probelm ill post what i came up with. I started using NSubstitute instead and it was quite easy

```
var serviceSub = Substitute.For<IService>();
serviceSub.Method1(Arg.Is<string>(arg => arg == "StringArgument1")).Returns(1);
serviceSub.Method1(Arg.Is<string>(arg => arg == "StringArgument2")).Returns(2);

var mobileServiceFacadeSub = Substitute.For<IServiceFacade>();
mobileServiceFacadeSub.Execute(Arg.InvokeDelegate<Func<IService, ICollection<TResult>>>(serviceSub));
```